# Unable to use two modals on same page using useDisclosure() in ChakraUI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, chakra-ui

There is a custom hook useDisclosure() provided by chakraUI which returns *isOpen, onClose , onOpen*.

```
  const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure()
```

The **onOpen** is passed to the onClick of the button which is triggered to open the modal.

```
<Modal isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onClose}>
  ...Modal Code...
<Modal/>

<Button onClick={onOpen}>
  button
<Button/>
```

Now I want to make another modal (lets say reportModal) on same page. For that I wrote the same code where I renamed variables while destructuring useDisclosure().

```
const {
        isOpen: { isOpenReportModal },
        onOpen: { onOpenReportModal },
        onClose: { onCloseReportModal },
      } = useDisclosure()
```

Further, I used the same flow by passing these renamed variables to  and  component but id didn't work.

Anyone for its solution?
Thanking in advance...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You have to rename the variables like this.

```
 const { 
    isOpen: isOpenReportModal, 
    onOpen: onOpenReportModal, 
    onClose: onCloseReportModal 
} = useDisclosure()
```

Now this should work. What you have tried is like destructuring again. Which is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I use following approach which is better than destructuring.

```
function MyApp() {
  const modal1 = useDisclosure()
  const modal2 = useDisclosure()
  
  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={modal1.onOpen}>Open Modal 1</Button>
      <Button onClick={modal2.onOpen}>Open Modal 2</Button>

      <Modal isOpen={modal1.isOpen} onClose={modal1.onClose}>
        // modal body
      </Modal>
      
      <Modal isOpen={modal2.isOpen} onClose={modal2.onClose}>
        // modal body
      </Modal>
    </>
  )
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/discussions/3378#discussioncomment-370870)